# Question about flat prior

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a bent coin with unknown probability θ of heads. We toss it 12 times and get 8 heads and 4 tails. Starting with a ﬂat prior, I want to show that the posterior pdf is a beta(9, 5) distribution.

**My Question:**

According to the solution set the prior should be $1\cdot d\theta$. Why? I would think flat means it is $\text{Unif}(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, then asserting  flat prior probability  over $[0,1]$ (continuous) is saying that
$$P(\Theta \in d\theta) = 1\,d\theta.$$
This gives that the **prior density** is 
$$f_\Theta(\theta) = 1$$
which is the density of a uniform random variable over $[0,1]$.

Comment: But what does $d\theta$ stand for? I don't get where it comes from.

Comment: @StanShunpike I can only give an intro probability explanation. Recall that for a continuous random variable $X$, $P(X = c) = 0$ for any $c$ for a distribution with a density. So instead we consider the event $(X \in dx)$, which stands for the event that $X$ falls in an infinitesimal width $dx$ near $x$, like $P(x\leq X\leq x+dx)$. The area representing $P(X\in dx)$ is essentially a rectangle of sides $f(x)$ and $dx$, and hence area $f(x)dx$. Then $P(X\in dx) = f(x)dx$, and so $f(x) = P(X\in dx)/dx$.